# How to fix konsole `\033[0m` not working start from second page of scroll?

Tags: colors, konsole

I noticed `konsole` has problem to reset color on next page of scrolling, as screenshot below, run with command `for i in {1..100}; do echo "$i"; echo -en '\033[1;42m AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  \033[0m'; echo -e 'next text'; done;` :

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the `\033[0m`  get ignored started from 11th row which is the next page of current window view.

`gnome-terminal` no such issue., but I'm `konsole` user and looking for a solution to this.

**[UPDATE]**

I reported bug at https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=409016

Comment: go [here](https://bugs.kde.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
\033[0m
```

to

```
\033[0m\033[K
```

that will do what you intended.  The difference is that when the terminal scrolls up, it will fill the new line with the current background color:

- The **`\E[K`** clears the current line from the current position to the end of the line (undoing the color-filling done by scrolling).
- The color behavior is a feature of [Linux console](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-slang.html#cause_bce_linux), implemented in other terminals (rxvt, xterm, konsole).

See also:

- [Background color whitespace when end of the terminal reached](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212933/background-color-whitespace-when-end-of-the-terminal-reached/237374#237374)

Comment: A reminder to reader, this is uppercase 'K',  can't use lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a similar problem using the bash looping construct `for $file in \'ls\'`. I had `ls` aliased to `ls -h --color=auto`. Unaliasing `ls` solved the problem, so apparently some color code was getting stored in `$file`.